# Is there a client application for the cloud service Cubby by LogMeIn?

Tags: software-recommendation, cloud

LogMeIn has provided clients for Windows and MacOS but are currently "working" on a linux version. Has anyone found/written one for linux. Running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I have found so far is to add it in your file manager as a webdav connection.   So far, it seems to work, but there is no syncing.

http://www.cubby.com/help/faq/default.aspx#unique_5